# How to send fake Accelerometer values to an app on a real device?

Tags: android, mocking, accelerometer

For example, [Location Spoofer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.ajeje.fakelocation&hl=en) gives out a fake location by using the Access Mock Location permission and I can make my device send out a signal that it's present in any place that I desire.

In the same way, can I fake the Accelerometer data to mock the various situations that a user can be in?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SensorSimulator](https://github.com/openintents/sensorsimulator) to simulate acceleration in your android device or emulator ([download link](https://code.google.com/archive/p/openintents/downloads)).

Comment: Are you sure this can be used on a real device. What I want is to fake the accelerometer values i.e. send false values to the apps that use accelerometer for example games etc.

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As i answered in this question: [Simulate accelerometer values on a real device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17574111/is-it-possible-to-simulate-accelerometer-motion-on-a-real-not-emulated-device/21761854#21761854)

You can send the values you want directly from your app, but i am not sure if you need to be root to do that.