# Is it possible to simulate accelerometer motion on a real (not emulated) device?

Tags: android, android-sensors

Is it possible to transmit fake values to the accelerometer sensor like it is possible with GPS coordinates?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the GPS location, then yes, you can fake that (look at the very bottom of the page):
[Android DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html#ops-location)

Using the DDMS, you can simply tell your device its current GPS coordinates.

EDIT: I guess, this post answers your question [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17062749/how-to-send-fake-accelerometer-values-to-an-app-on-a-real-device). It points out that [SensorSimulator](https://code.google.com/p/openintents/wiki/SensorSimulator) is capable of doing that. If you scroll down a little bit on the page, it explains you how to connect the tool with a real device. I myself have never used it, so just try it :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but first of all i want to simulate accelerometer

Comment: That mentioned SensorSimulator helps to simulate sensors on emulator, and you can use their lib to use simulated values in your app, but i want to simulate values to every app, that uses standard SensorManager) But +1 for an answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that if you find the input event file, and write the values directly to the file. 
`ls -l /dev/input/` 
and you will see the list of the events you may access.
Not sure if you need to be root for that (which can be the case).

Comment: 1. Can you explain what data (data format) should be written to this file ?
2. How dose this newly written data gets interpreted by system ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to follow the logic and reached this area of the code: https://github.com/mozilla-b2g/android-device-crespo/tree/master/libsensors which refers to gyros and whatnot in the various device builds

The code actually makes reference to chip-specific /dev files and paths like /sys/devices/platform/soc-audio.0/sound/card0/pcmC0D9p/dev which I could probably work out how to interpret, but fear I've already squandered too much time on.

It looks like if you're going to try this, you'd need to pretend to be a variety of accelerometer chips, but I *suspect* squirting data into them is unlikely to work the same way it does with the easier devices.